# Call mutation observer after response received from background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I am working on a chrome extension and i need to do some dom changes once i have received my stores data from background script. But the problem is that mutation observer won't wait for the stores to be received from the background script. How can i make my script wait for response from background script and then do changes in dom. Here is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "stores"}, function(response) {
     stores = response.data;
});

var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) { 
mutations.some(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes && (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)) { 
        var node = mutation.target.querySelector("div#search");
        if (node) {
            observer1.disconnect();
                modifyLinks(node,stores);
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: You can't wait. The messaging is async only. But you can fetch the data sooner. Or save the mutations in a global variable and process them in the message listener.\

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the help. I saved the mutations in global variable and processed them in message listener and it worked like champ.